# Jenkins stage exited with code 1 and passing stage

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy

in my pipeline one of the stage is exited with code 1 and still pipeline is passing. I want to fail the pipeline stage with exception when it is exiting with code 1.

Here is stage code:

```
stage('Stage A'){
  steps{
    script{
      container('A'){
        sh "$Command"
                def exitCode = sh 'echo $?'
                if (exitCode == 1) {
                     sh "exit 1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31o8h.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to error out the Pipeline you can use [error signal](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal).

```
def exitCode = sh script:"$Command", returnStatus:true
if (exitCode == 1) {
     error "Exit code is 1, so erroring out!"
}
```

Comment: with the code shared above i'm not able to fetch exit code 1. even if it is 1 i'm getting 0. ------------------------------------------------------ --------------------smoke-suite-1 exited with code 1 [Pipeline] sh + echo 0 0 –